# jQuery code behaves differently on IPHONE4s, IPHONE5, and IPHONE5s

Tags: jquery

I have IPhone4s,IPhone5,IPhone5s which all run the same iOS version 7.1.1(11D201). However, the following JQUERY only works fine with IPHONE5s. On the other 2 IPhones, the click event doesn't fire at all. When i changed to the inline onclick event, it works fine on all phones.

However, this is strange as all of these IPhones run the same version of iOS and supposedly mobile safari.

Any idea why the JQUERY code behaves different on the IPhones running same iOS?

```
$('#arrow_offer').on('click', function () {
 if ($("#toggledivoffer").css('display') == "none") {
    $('#toggledivoffer').css('display', 'block');
    $('#arrow_offer').css("background-image","url('images/arrowdown.png')");
 }
 else{
    $('#toggledivoffer').css('display', 'none');
    $('#arrow_offer').css("background-image","url('images/arrow.png')");
 }
});
<p class="arrow" id="arrow_offer"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `is(':visible')` instead of checking `display` property. And also use `.show()` and `.hide()` instead of changing `display` property to show and hide element.

```
$('#arrow_offer').on('click', function () {
 if (!$("#toggledivoffer").is(':visible')) {
    $('#toggledivoffer').show();
    $('#arrow_offer').css("background-image","url('images/arrowdown.png')");
 }
 else{
    $('#toggledivoffer').hide();
    $('#arrow_offer').css("background-image","url('images/arrow.png')");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this behaves differently but i can suggest you to toggle the classes/toggle the div:

```
 $('#arrow_offer').on('click', function () {
     $('#toggledivoffer').toggle(); // toggles the visibility of div
     $('#arrow_offer').toggleClass("arrow arrowdown"); // toggles the classes
 });
```

where css classes are as follows:

```
.arrow{
  background: url('images/arrow.png');
}
.arrowdown{
  background: url('images/arrowdown.png');
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52e6j/)